# could not access file "/usr/lib64/pgsql/plpgsql.so" in windows for PostgreSQL

Tags: windows, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL 8.3 for windows. But while creating the database I am getting the following error:

```
could not access file "/usr/lib64/pgsql/plpgsql.so": No such file or directory
```

I am looking for the path specified above in the installation directory but I am not getting anything.

Please help me or give any suggestions.

Comment: This release is ancient, and it sounds like it's probably a cygwin based one to boot. Use an installer for a current version like 9.4; see http://www.postgresql.org/download/

Comment: I am finding the same error with 9.4 version also. As per the error is concern its looking like the error is for linux.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you be more specific about exactly what you are doing? How exactly do you create the database?